# Apply button not active in Nvidia Xserver configuration settings in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xserver

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 but when I want to connect an external monitor, TV or projector it does not recognise it anymore (it used to with Ubuntu 09.04). I opened the Xserver configutation settings and the primary laptop is disabled, it detect the external display but whatever I change, the APPLY button is not activated. Please help me . I am not an Ubuntu expert but I love it and would like to keep using it.
Nour

Answer (score 0):

Try this in terminal

> gksudo nvidia-settings

This should allow you to save the changes

Good Luck - Mal

Comment: Thank you for replying so fast but it does not work. The apply button is still not clickable in the Nvidia Xserver Display Configuration.

Comment: Hi Nour, try sudo as opposed to gksudo. There are subtle differences in the command. Both "should" work, I am amazed that it does not.

Comment: No, it is the same. The apply button is not "on". What else can it be that changed from before, when I was running the Ubuntu 09.04? I have a Dell Vostro 1500, if that helps. I thank in anticipation every one who can help!

Comment: I do not use Ubuntu 12.04, However, a long shot - is the driver "active"? go to (in 11.04 classic) system-administration-additional drivers. Click on this and it should tell you if the driver is active - if not, activate it. The community may if they read this "edit" my answer to be more specific to 12.04.